# How to calculate consistent tangent vectors over a mesh surface?

Tags: opengl

Bump mapping in OpenGL shaders is usually done in `tangent space`, which has the normal, tangent and binormal as base vectors.

According to my book, *OpenGL Shading Language*, it is required that the base vectors are `consistently oriented across the surface of the object` for the lighting equations to interpolate correctly. It also defines that by consistent, it means consistent with respect to the normal map texture coordinates.

So given the vertex positions, normals and normal map texture coordinates for an arbitrary mesh, how can I calculate consistent tangent vectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calculating tangent and bitangent vectors so they orient correctly with texture coordinates, and correctly match the normals is actually fairly complicated.

A good code sample I have used in the past is this one:
http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html

Crytek also has a presentation on this topic. Their implementation also solves many common problems with tangent space calculation:
http://crytek.com/cryengine/presentations/triangle-mesh-tangent-space-calculation

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will check them out.